# For or Repeat Loop to filter based on String Value rather than a sequence of numbers

Tags: r, loops

I am having trouble using a For Loop to sequentially filter and perform operations on a larger dataset of transactional data, based on the unique style numbers found in the dataframe cur.

I have a one-column dataframe of unique string values (cur), and I need to filter a larger data set, sequentially based on each value in the unique datafram of strings.

I have tried using a for loop such as the following:

```
cur <- data.frame(
  `Style-Brand` = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"))
dem2 <- data.frame(
  `Brand` = c("a" , "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
  `Week` = c("8-20-2017", "8-20-2017", "8-20-2017", "8-20-2017", "8-20-2017", "8-20-2017"),
  `Units Sold` = c("1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2"),
  `Style-Brand` = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"))

for (i in cur) {

  demx <- dem2 %>% filter(`Style-Brand` == i)
```

After doing the sequential filter, I execute a bunch of other operations on just the subset of data that I selected here and then store the output values to a dataframe. I need to perform the filter, run through the block of code below, and the loop back to the next string in the list.

As I understand it the more I read, the For loop only works with the index of a rows? And you also need to know the number of rows in advance?

Can anyone please suggest another way I might be able to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can `split` into a `list` instead of looping and `filter`ing `lst1 <- split(cur, cur$Style.Brand)`  In the `for` loop you may need to loop by unique values of that column and not the whole dataset

Comment: Apologies, can you maybe illustrate how I might loop by unique values of the column? Thank you!

Comment: As akrun mentions, can you not do `split(dem2, dem2$\`Style-Brand\`)` and then apply the operations to each list using `lapply` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should start by allocating enough space for your list using `vector`. It's not really a problem here, but growing lists can really slow R down if you have more data. You can then iterate over the integer positions of `cur$Style.Brand`, assigning the `filter` output to the `i`th element of `df_list`:

```r
df_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(cur))

for (i in seq_along(cur$Style.Brand)) {
    df_list[[i]] <- dplyr::filter(dem2, Style.Brand == cur$Style.Brand[i])
}
```

Alternatively you can try using lapply, which is a little simpler:

```r
lapply(cur$Style.Brand, function(s) dplyr::filter(dem2, Style.Brand == s))
```

The output for both options should look like this:

```
[[1]]
  Brand      Week Units.Sold Style.Brand
1     a 8-20-2017          1          aa

[[2]]
  Brand      Week Units.Sold Style.Brand
1     b 8-20-2017          2          bb

[[3]]
  Brand      Week Units.Sold Style.Brand
1     c 8-20-2017          1          cc

[[4]]
  Brand      Week Units.Sold Style.Brand
1     d 8-20-2017          1          dd

[[5]]
  Brand      Week Units.Sold Style.Brand
1     e 8-20-2017          1          ee

[[6]]
  Brand      Week Units.Sold Style.Brand
1     f 8-20-2017          2          ff
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
library(dplyr)
cur <-  c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff")
dem2 <- data.frame(
  `Brand` = c("a" , "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
  `Week` = c("8-20-2017", "8-20-2017", "8-20-2017", "8-20-2017", "8-20-2017", "8-20-2017"),
  `Units Sold` = c("1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2"),
  `Style-Brand` = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"))

dem <- list() 
j = 1
for (i in cur) {
 dem[[j]] <- dem2 %>% filter(Style.Brand == i)
 j = j + 1
}  
dem
```

Answer (score 1):

A for loop isn't really necessary here. You can use `dplyr::group_split` or `split` to split a data frame into a list of data frames based on values in one column:

```r
library(dplyr)
group_split(dem2, Style.Brand) # dpylyr option
split(dem2, dem2$Style.Brand)  # base R option

#### OUTPUT ####
$aa
  Brand      Week Units.Sold Style.Brand
1     a 8-20-2017          1          aa

$bb
  Brand      Week Units.Sold Style.Brand
2     b 8-20-2017          2          bb

$cc
  Brand      Week Units.Sold Style.Brand
3     c 8-20-2017          1          cc

$dd
  Brand      Week Units.Sold Style.Brand
4     d 8-20-2017          1          dd

$ee
  Brand      Week Units.Sold Style.Brand
5     e 8-20-2017          1          ee

$ff
  Brand      Week Units.Sold Style.Brand
6     f 8-20-2017          2          ff
```